# Swift - change height of mapview inside a tableView

Tags: swift, height, mapkit, tableview, android-mapview

(Look at ##Edit##)
I'm a beginner. I used google but can't find a solution for my problem.

How can I change the height of my MapView inside the tableView?

My storyboard looks like:
[click here I cant post pictures](http://stirnraten.de/eras/lange/height.png)

I can change the size of the MKMapView however I want but nothing changed "in real/in the emulator".

I tried to change the size of the cells with:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
         return 500
    }
    
    return 75.0
}
```

But indexPath.row=0 ist the first entry "Name: Test"

Can somebody explain how and why I can't change the size? How can I change the size?

Thank u for help.

### EDIT

I tried it with two different cells ("Map Cell" and "listAllBakeries") and now it works with the size.

When I click on an entry there isn't an update at the "Map Cell" but on the "listAllBakeries". [More than one Map](http://stirnraten.de/eras/lange/morethanonemap.png)

The code:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //CODE TO BE RUN ON CELL TOUCH

    //get the Location with latitude and longitude
    var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude[indexPath.item], longitude: longitude[indexPath.item])
    
    //resolution
    var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.003, 0.003)
    var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location,span:span)
    
    
    //here is the mistake
    let cell2:ListPlacesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListPlacesTableViewCell
    
    //some Text about the Place
    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation() 
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = namesBakeries[indexPath.item]
    annotation.subtitle = "some Text"
    
    //Zooming inside the map
    cell2.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    cell2.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    
}
```

I don't really understand this. I use the right identifier (MapCell) but the section/row is wrong. How can I use the right section?

Here is my code how I fill the rows/section

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        let cell2:ListPlacesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListPlacesTableViewCell
        
        //insert MapStuff
        //addAnnotations
       //MapStuff
        

        return cell2
    
    } else {
        //Standard-Labels with text
        let cell:ListPlacesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("listAllBakeries", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListPlacesTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel?.text = namesBakeries[indexPath.row]
        cell.adressLabel?.text = "Test 2"
          return cell
    }    
}
```

Thank for help

(I'm sorry for my english but this isn't my mothertongue).

Comment: You cannot change the row height because in storyboard the mapview is not a cell, but a header, is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your map is above the uiTableView rather than a separate prototype cell in your table.

Set your uiTableView up with 2 prototype cells then put the map in the first.

Then, as you have done, you can test the value of indexpath.row.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out.

The trick is to update always the same cell.
I defined an array. Then save my Cell2 in this array and just used this Object to update my map. (My english is awful I know, maybe my code will give more information.)

```
class ListPlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController {


var constantCell = [ListPlacesTableViewCell?](count: 1, repeatedValue: nil)
....
//other stuff here

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        let cell2:ListPlacesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListPlacesTableViewCell

        constantCell[0] = cell2
//other stuff here
}
}
//Clickable Cell Function add:
 constantCell[0]!.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    constantCell[0]!.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Thanks for help